# Sample size calculation for several candidates (n > 2)

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, sample-size

Let say I want to support level for several candidates `A, B, C.` When number of candidates is greater than 2. And I want to calculate minimum sample size (calculate not chose number like 1000).
 I see a lot of examples with 2 candidates A and B. or `support A /opposite A` questions, but I can't find how to calculate sample size to find support level for several. 
 I think that is not *binomial distribution* because n(candidates) > 2. And this is not fully *normal distribution* because only subset of real numbers is affected. Can you help with this?